# Show that $\{xy : x \in \{a\}^*, y \in \{b\}^*, |x| = |y|\}$ is a not a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma, nondeterminism

I have been asked as an exercise how to prove that this is not a regular language. first I tried to use the pumping lemma, but I got stucked. Th erxercise hust said to prove thata this isn't a regular language, I would appreciate if the answer could e given step by step, I really wnat to understand how it works .

Thank you :)

Show that $\{xy : x \in \{a\}^*, y \in \{b\}^*, |x| = |y|\}$ is a not a regular language

Comment: This is the first example that textbooks usually give.

Comment: Please see tips and suggestions in our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/4287).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Answer (score 1):

Assume L is regular and is recognised by a state machine with N states. Then the strings $a^k$ for 0 ≤ k ≤ N cannot all end up in different states, because that would be N+1 different states. Therefore there are k ≠ k' such that $a^k$ and $a^{k'}$ end up in the same state.

If $a^k$ and $a^{k'}$ end up in the same state, then $a^k w$ and $a^{k'} w$ also end up in the same state, for every w. We pick $w = b^k$, and $a^k b^k$ and $a^{k'} b^k$ end up in the same state. However, the first is in the language and the second is not. Therefore the state would have to be both an accepting and a non accepting state, which is not possible. Therefore L is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be your language. Suppose towards a contradiction that $L$ is regular and let $p$ be it's pumping length.
Consider the word $a^pb^p \in L$. By the pumping lemma we can write it as $a^i a^j b^p$ with $j \ge i$ in such a way that, for all $k \ge i$, $a^i a^{jk} b^p \in L$.
Pick $k=0$ to obtain $a^i b^p \in L$. This provides the sought contradiction since $i < p$.

Answer (score 0):

isn't this the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309752/why-is-anbn-n-0-not-regular

$if  \,\,\,\, |x|=|y| \,\,\,\, then \,\,\,\  L = \{a^n b^n \mid n \geq 0\} $

Comment: I don't understand why the answer got downvoted, I simply referenced to the question, which I think is the same. I would like to know, why question I linked not the same as the question asked here.

Comment: This here answer does not *show that that language is a not a regular*, let alone *step by step*.

Comment: following link contains answers to the question above.